# css page-break-after: avoid; doesn't work in <h1></h1><p></p> pattern

Tags: css, pdf, markdown, wkhtmltopdf, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a markdown with a css style sheet to pdf. I use page-break-after: avoid; for my headers but it doesn't work.

To convert to pdf I use `pandoc` and `wkhtmltopdf` like that: `pandoc -t html --css mycss.css mymd.md -o mypdf.pdf --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf --pdf-engine-opt=--print-media-type`

mycss.css file is:

```
@media print {
    h1 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    p {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}

body {
    font-size: 100%;
}

* {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #222;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 35px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

h1 {
    color: #0047b3;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

mymd.md file is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

# Should be page 2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

# Another title
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

And it prints the title in page 1 instead of page 2 like that:

[image: result]

What is wrong here ?

If I generate the HTML file with `pandoc -t html --css mycss.css mymd.md -o myhtml.html` and I get :

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<h1 id="should-be-page-2">Should be page 2</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<h1 id="another-title">Another title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Thank you for your help.

Izaya

Comment: Are you sure the HTML generated by pandoc consists entirely of <h1>s and <p>s? You could get the above result if there was a <br> in between.

Comment: The HTML generated by pandoc is: `<p> [...] laborum.</p><h1 id="should-be-page-2">Should be page 2</h1><p>Lorem ipsum [...] </p>`. So it's not because of something between </h2> and <p>.

Comment: Try removing the `@media print` ?

Comment: Tried but nothing changed.